# what do I research?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to know what is happening when extra bits of information are passed around through method titles in xcode ie:

```
- (CGPDFPageRef)pdfPage:(NSInteger)index {
```

and

```
- (void)configurePageP:(ISVportrate *)page forIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
```

when this happens it is a little annoying that I don't know whats going on or feel comfortable passing messages this way my self.

for example my app is made from some code chunks stuck together in a voodoo manner, one part of my app passes a message to a class this way... but the class only declares NSInteger index but never uses it:

```
@interface ImageScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    NSUInteger     index;
}
@property (assign) NSUInteger index;
@end

@implementation ImageScrollView
@synthesize index;
@end
```

I would really like to research this, can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's just passing arguments with the message, similar to how `printf("Hello\n")` passes `"Hello\n"` to the `printf` function.

Apple's free [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) explains this very well, in addition to many other concepts that are important for you to feel confident in understanding Objective-C code. The first chapter after the introduction is actually on this very topic.